# Number of integers for which tan|x|=|tanx|

Tags: trigonometry

Find the number of integers for which tan|x|=|tanx|.$x\in(-2\pi,2\pi)$

I used **desmos.com** and found the following x coordinate where the curve
y=tan|x|and

y=|tanx|intersect.
The points are at x=0,+1,-1,+4,-4.
Hence the number of integers where it intersect is 5.
Please help me with finding the correct answer I am not sure about it.

Comment: ...? What's wrong with the answer you gave?

Comment: Actually I showed my student the solution of the following equation in desmos.com but they were not convinced, they wanted solution using mathematical equation. Hence I decided to post this question

Comment: That's the sort of context you should add to your question from the beginning to help avoid it getting closed on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline/Hint**: First, there's an obvious solution at $x=0$. Then since $\tan|x|$ is even you just need to find solutions in the interval $(0,2\pi)$. Notice that on this interval $\tan\!|x| = |\tan(x)|$ exactly when $\tan(x)$ is positive. On which intervals is $\tan(x)$ positive? Then which of the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ live in these intervals?